# How can I select multiple parents and their children?

Tags: selection-tools, collections

I have a multi-object structure (parents and children). In the Outliner, if I select objects and move them to a collection, it will move the object but NOT the child. So I have to select the hierarchy before moving to a collection. But I have multiple objects with their own children. How can I select the parents and select their hierarchies? I can only select a hierarchy for a single object. So to move multiple object with children to a collection I have to repeat the process for each of those parents.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the parents that you wanna move and then go to Select > Select More / Less > Extend to children. Or Shift + ]<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: what version is that ? in 2.83.3 i select more/less. there is no 'extend to children' , only more or less option. If i select more , it will select both parent and children. I want to select children only.

Comment: 2.83.4 I have the option, make sure is in object mode, other than that, not sure why you don't have it. It's in the manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/selecting.html

Comment: i just installed 2.83.4 and still the same. Maybe because i'm using mac version ?

Comment: SOrry i don't own a Mac to check, i think they should be the same, try to check if they have a bug report or something about mac here : https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/