# When moving objects to a collection, not all selected objects are moved. Why?

Tags: blend-files, collections, outliner

I am working on a fairly large scene that has a lot of mesh data, active booleans, and mirrors. I am trying to clean up the file so it's more easy to manage. What I have been doing is moving major parts to their own collections.

Anyway, when I select the objects to move and then press <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Move to Collection</kbd>, not all of the selected objects are moved. There are always a few left behind. If I select the objects that are remaining and again select "Move to Collection", some of them move, but yet again a few are left behind.

If I repeat this process over and over, eventually everything gets moved properly, but it bothers me that there is no explanation to this behavior.

Here is a video of what I am talking about:

https://streamable.com/yvm9eu

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you are probably selecting Parents but not the child, you need to select all of them, If that is the case... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190631/how-can-i-select-multiple-parents-and-their-children/190713#190713

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be part of the reason - but if that's the case, why does it work after the 2nd-3rd attempt? Does the action of moving a parent to a different collection break its relationship with its children?

Comment: no it doesn't break the relationship, you're talking about the 2nd and 3rd attempt but actually these times you were just putting the children into the collection then the children of the children, isn't it? by the way in my opinion it would make sense that the children would follow by default...